# TreeViewItem do not get highlighted on Single click WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, winrt-xaml, treeviewitem

I have a simple tree, it works fine, but it does not get highlighted on Single click, the user needs to double click.

The commands bonded to it works fine on single click.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ElementsTypes}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
                    <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick"
                                      Command="{Binding ElementsCommand}"
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                    </TextBlock.InputBindings>
                </TextBlock>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your `MouseBinding` is "stealing" your left click. One possible solution would be to add `IsSelected` property to your ViewModel and set it to `true` on `ElementsCommand`:

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
           <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
      </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>


public class MyTreeElement
{
    private bool _IsSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _IsSelected; }
        set 
          { 
              _IsSelected = value; 
              OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
          }
    }
    private void ElementsCommandMethod(object item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ElementsCommand");
        IsSelected = true;
    }
}
```

This way you will also know which item in your ViewModel is selected and will be able to manipulate the selection programmatically from the ViewModel.